# Ignore specific occurrence of string while replacing

Tags: c#, parsing, replace

I'm trying to parse a database and replace ":" with another delimiter such as "+delimiter+". The problem with this is this specific database has a hash:salt combo. Some of the salts contain extra ":"'s and some don't. How would I go about replacing all ":"'s and ignoring the ones in the hashes

Example:

```
1:john:john@john.com:127.0.0.1:341b4d30d4f5bb31f291633e0c97a8ba:J:|
```

I want to ignore the colons in:

```
341b4d30d4f5bb31f291633e0c97a8ba:J:|
```

But I want to replace the other colons with "+delimiter+"

Comment: Have a look at string.Split overloads ;o)

Comment: will there always be a minimum number of `:` characters? and is that determinable enough to split on? like split on the 4th colon? replace `:` on the first part then `string.Join(<delimiter>, part1, part2)` the result?

Comment: @BrettCaswell the max number of ":" characters i saw was 7. So I guess i want to ignore the 6th and 7th occurrences. But the 7th occurrence doesn't always exist nor does the 6th

Answer (score 1):

The [`String.Split()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda(v=vs.110).aspx) takes a `count` as its second argument:

```
string input = "1:john:john@john.com:127.0.0.1:341b4d30d4f5bb31f291633e0c97a8ba:J:|";
string[] fields = input.Split(new[]{ ':' }, 5);
```

The string `fields[4]` now holds the value `341b4d30d4f5bb31f291633e0c97a8ba:J:|`

To complete the replace operation, apply String.Join to concatenate the strings using the new delimiter:

```
string result = String.Join("+delimiter+", fields);
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, I believe OP was asking how to replace the ':' delimiter ignoring the same character in the last (hashed) field.  Your answer doesn't address this.

Comment: Easy from here, just apply `String.Join()` on `fields`

Comment: You should add it to your answer :-) WIthout it, it doesn't answer the question!

Answer (score 1):

If your string will always be in the format you've specified:

`1:john:john@john.com:127.0.0.1:341b4d30d4f5bb31f291633e0c97a8ba:J:|`

You can use the `String.Split(Char[], Int32)` overload to specify the maximum number of substrings returned.  Specify `5` substrings and the final substring will contain the remainder of the input string i.e. the hashed field.

```
string input = "1:john:john@john.com:127.0.0.1:341b4d30d4f5bb31f291633e0c97a8ba:J:|";
string[] array = input.Split(new char[] { ':' }, 5);
```

You can then use the String.Join method to concatenate the string array with the desired separator.

```
string output = String.Join("+delimiter+", array);
```